# Android linear layout. 2 rows of 2

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout with 4 text views (2 labels, 2 with data) in the following structure

```
Label    Label
Data     Data
```

I would like to double the above but I'm having great difficulty.
The desire is

```
Label    Label
Data     Data
Label    Label
Data     Data
```

This is code for what I have so far. When i add more text views it throws positioning off.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/temperatureLabel"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/label"
            android:textColor="#80ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/data"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/label"
            android:textColor="#80ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/data"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: could you put a screenshot of what you want?

Comment: What was the code you wanted before and after? What did it look like before and after?

Comment: Structure Updated

Comment: your views have same id - this one should be fixed - compile error. First LinearLayout has android:layout_height="match_parent" this result to first LinearLayout be visible and second will not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to just double it or have a table like layout. You could use gridLayout to solve your problem.

eg.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    app:columnCount="2"
    app:rowCount="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="abel"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="data"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="abel"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="data"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="abel"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="data"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="abel"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="data"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout> </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Android gives me errors relating to layout row and all that

Comment: It was missing a closing tag on the code I posted. Could you try again?
I tested it and it works fine around here

Comment: Okay, got it. You have to add the following line in your Gradle file  **compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'** or newer version of the same library

Comment: Fantastic thanks very much. One more question if you don't mind. What's the best way to move the elemenets down the page.

Comment: I updated the answer to help you achieve that. Basically, your grid layout needs to be inside another layout such as a FrameLayout that has a width and height of match parent and then you can set the layout_gravity of your grid layout to bottom

Answer (score 0):

To avoid nesting layouts could use Constraint Layout and setting the horizontal and vertical constraints for each view to get the positioning you want.

```
<ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/data1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Data1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/label1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/label1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/data2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Data2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/label2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/data1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/label1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/data3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Data3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/label3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/data2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/label2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/data4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Data4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/label4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label4" />
```